# Uniqueness check in Deequ

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-deequ

I'm currently exploring Deequ library and I'm trying to understand whether it's possible to check for the uniqueness of a combination of column.

This code

```
.hasUniqueness(Seq("col1", "col2"), Check.IsOne))
```

seems to calculate uniqueness for each column separately (correct if I'm wrong)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am one of the authors of Deequ. Your code snippet should calculate the uniqueness of the combined columns. If you feel that something is wrong with the result, then I would encourage you to open an issue at https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/issues and provide some sample code so that we can reproduce the error.

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: Thanks! Removed in favor of your answer.

Comment: Sebastian, many thanks for your reply. Perhaps there is something I don't understand here but if .hasUniqueness(Seq("col1"), Check.IsOne)) returns Success  I would expect .hasUniqueness(Seq("col1", "col2"), Check.IsOne)) to be a Success as well . A combination of a unique column and a non-unique one should still be unique, right?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case.

Comment: ok, appears not to follow this rule if one of the columns contains nulls

Comment: We fixed this problem in Deequ recently, will cut a release with the fix soon.